# Is there a way of printing coloured text in python but the colour is an RGB value?

Tags: python, text, colors

I've been trying to find a way to output some coloured text in Python 3.10.8 however all the libraries I have found only have preset list of colours you can choose from and apply to the text. Is there a way to set text to a specific colour provided by a RGB value?

I've looked into multiple libraries such as termcolour and colourma but they only have a specific list of colours you can use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to print from Python using non-ANSI colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851356/is-it-possible-to-print-from-python-using-non-ansi-colors)

Comment: Sure, **rich**, see https://pypi.org/project/rich/ Use *"styles"* for hex colours https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style.html

Comment: Note: most terminals do not support all RGB colours, and on "named" colours: different terminals uses different "shades" (sometime different hue). And people (like me) redefine the colour of terminal, and it is difficult to know if a person has a dark or a light terminal preference. So: if you do it, be careful and be configurable (on colour schema).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, ended up using `print(f'\033[38;2;{red};{green};{blue}m{text}\033[0m',end="")`. Not elegant but it works.